# Is there a way to replace a repeated word in a string but only in specific positions?

Tags: python

> For example:

```
ExampleString="yes\n no\n yes\n yes\n no\n yes\n"
ExpectedString="yes no yes\n yes no yes"
```

> Trying to replace `\n` for `""` but every 3 `"\n"` don't replace it, imagine it like an infinite string with that repetition.

Comment: You need to split the list into its component parts and then "chunk" it into groups of 3.  With that search term, you should be able to find the missing part of the solution.

Comment: How can I do that, I'm sorry for not knowing.

Comment: What part confuses you?  How to search for "Python list chunk"?  Do that reading, make a valid attempt, and then try asking again if you still have trouble.

Answer (score 2):

For fun, here is a one-liner (two-liner, since you have to import itertools):

```
>>> import itertools as it
>>> '\n'.join(map(''.join, it.zip_longest(*[iter(ExampleString.split('\n'))]*3, fillvalue='')))
'yes no yes\n yes no yes\n'
```

But I don't recommend it, since it will likely confuse any reader of your code (hence I'm also hesitant to explain it).

Answer (score 1):

Split the string using `.split('\n')`

Group them using `zip(*[iter(split_string + [''] * (group_size - len(split_string) % group_size))] * group_size)`

Turn each group into the combined string using `''.join()`

Recombine the strings using `'\n'.join()`

```
string = "yes\n no\n yes\n yes\n no\n yes\n"

group_size = 3

split_string = string.split('\n')

chunks = zip(*[iter(split_string + [''] * (group_size - len(split_string) % group_size))] * group_size)

new_string = '\n'.join([''.join(i) for i in chunks])

print(new_string)
```

Output

```
yes no yes
 yes no yes
```

Answer (score 0):

replace a word or character on specific position.

```
str = 'yes\n no\n yes\n yes\n no\n yes\n'
new_character = ''
while(True):
    position = int(input())
    str = str[:position] + new_character + str[position + 1:]
    print(str)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way

```
s = "yes\n no\n yes\n yes\n no\n yes\n".split(" ")
# s => ['yes\n', 'no\n', 'yes\n', 'yes\n', 'no\n', 'yes\n']
s = " ".join([(c + 1) % 3 == 0 and s[c] or s[c][:s[c].find("\n")] for c in range(len(s))])
# s => "yes no yes\n yes no yes\n"
```

Here we use the same with another string

```
s = "hi\n welcome\n okay\n thanks\n ok\n bye\n".split(" ")
# s => ['hi\n', 'welcome\n', 'okay\n', 'thanks\n', 'ok\n', 'bye\n']
s = " ".join([(c + 1) % 3 == 0 and s[c] or s[c][:s[c].find("\n")] for c in range(len(s))])
# s => "hi welcome okay\n thanks ok bye\n"
```